# reusable expressions in Context free grammars

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

say, we add the option of allowing `let` expressions to context free grammars:

`let` defines a variable that defines an expression from a specific Symbol of the grammar, and every instance of the variable has to be the exact same expression

eg:

```
T := (let ((z -> U) z + z)
U := x | y | Const | U +U | U ∗U | T
```

In the above example, `T:= U + U`, except that the two occurrences of `U`
have to be identical.

So, this grammar only allows expressions which are a sum of 2 identical expressions.

I think this grammar is strictly more powerful than context free grammar, but can anyone tell me if they are equivalent to any other known type of grammar.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Misread the site. So, formally speaking, what is `Int` in your example? Also, you might want to take a glance at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Wijngaarden_grammar

Comment: By the way, your `T` with `U := {a,b}*` proves that your model is strictly more powerful than CFL. It's *probably* not equivalent to CSL, though. So it falls in the class of "[mildly context-sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mildly_context-sensitive_grammar_formalism)" models, of which there are many. I suggest you start with that list and a Google Scholar query.